# Custom proxy entities for fixture generation

Tags: symfony, testing, doctrine-orm

So my question is very specific but I couldn't figure out how to make it even after several months of reflection. The following topic will be about Symfony, Doctrine and generating fixtures on-the-go for the tests.

I want to generate fixtures on the go from a test. The goal is to provide a very specific set of fixtures for each tests using helpers without sacrify the readability. That is the goal, so my idea was to create a `tests/Resources/EntityProxy` which is a mirror of the `src/Entity` folder, containing the same amount of classes with the exact same name. Each `EntityProxy` extends from its related `Entity`, use a custom trait to fill the properties easily.

You guessed it, I want to only use in tests the `EntityProxy` and use it directly into the functions to tests them. And there is a major issue with that, as Doctrine doesn't recognize the `EntityProxy` as an entity even if it extends from a real `Entity`.

Is there a way to say to Doctrine to persist an `EntityProxy` as its extended `Entity`?

__

The following code is an example of what I want as en `EntityProxy`:

```php
namespace Tests\Resources\EntityProxy;

class User extends App\Entity\User
{
    use FixtureGenerationTrait;

    public function static makeDefault(): self
    {
        return static::generate([
           'username' => self::getFaker()->username,
           'email'    => self::getFaker()->email,
           ...
        ]);
    }

    public function static make(array $data = []): self
    {
        $entity = static::makeDefault();
        $entity = static::setValues($entity, $data);

        return $entity;
    }
}
```

And can be used in the tests like following: `User::make(['name' => 'John Wick']);`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use it this way? Why not fill the fields of your entities through reflection?

Comment: Because it looses some clarity. One of the big issue of our tests is fixture generation. 
If we have a common database that is reset on each tests, adding a fixture may result of other tests failures. 

Adding only the fixture you need for each test seems the best approach but that creates a lot of redundancy and therefore less readable tests. I would like to improve the fixture generation by providing "generation" methods and "edition" methods right from the proxy, which can be used as the actual entity.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/nelmio/alice - this looks like what you are looking for, except it skips the proxy part

Comment: This is really a cool bundle, I totally forgot that it exists and I will integrate it to my bundle as well, thanks @NicoHaase :) ! Still, I let the question opened as I really want to try this implementation for very specific domain stuff